# Use Enum value without .value attribute

Tags: python

```
class Color(Enum):
    GREEN = '#1c5f17'
    BLUE = '#565fcc'
```

Is it possible to call
`Color.GREEN` and return '#1c5f17'?

I don't want to call `Color.GREEN.value` everytime I want to use this.

Comment: No, it's not. You generally wouldn't use `Color.GREEN.value` *anywhere*, you'd have `Color.GREEN` being used at a high level of abstraction, and `color.value` down at a lower level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want the traditional-style "call", just drop the inheritance from `Enum`:

```
class Color:
    GREEN = '#1c5f17'
    BLUE = '#565fcc'
```

Comment: I wonder how this compares to Jarrod Burns's answer

Comment: @ShankaraNarayana Look at the dates of the answers.

Comment: Trouble with this is it doesn't make the class immutable, which for me is the main reason for using Enum.

Comment: I am trying to love Enum but the .value is really annoying so I often result to this.

Answer (score 9):

IIRC prior to Python 3.11 the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum) recommended subclassing string:

```
class Sample(str, Enum):
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"
    BAZ = "baz"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str.__str__(self)
```

```
print(Sample.FOO)
>>> foo
```

But python 3.11+ users can import StrEnum:

```
from enum import StrEnum, auto

class Sample(StrEnum):
    FOO = auto()
    BAR = auto()
    BAZ = auto()
```

*Note: Using auto with StrEnum results in the lower-cased member name as the value.*

```
print(Sample.FOO)
>>> foo
```

If you prefer uppercase values:

```
from enum import StrEnum

class Sample(StrEnum):
    FOO = "FOO"
    BAR = "BAR"
    BAZ = "BAZ"
```

```
print(Sample.FOO)
>>> FOO
```

Comment: Your solution is wrong and don't answer the OP question.  print() works different from calling the value of the enum. So passing it as a variable still will pass a enum value. I will give you a simple example:

>> class TequilaUrls(StrEnum):
        BASE_URL = "https://api.tequila.kiwi.com/"
        FLIGHT_SEARCH = BASE_URL + "v2/search?"
        FIND_LOCATION = BASE_URL + "locations/query?"
>> TequilaUrls.BASE_URL
<TequilaUrls.BASE_URL: 'https://api.tequila.kiwi.com/'>

So, if you wan to pass it as a string, you still have to use value().

Comment: @Lukas I believe you have misunderstood the question, and that you are applying your own circumstances to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to Enum some variables to be used as indexes in a big matrix, and I also wanted to remove the .value necessity of the default implementation so I came up with this:

```
from enum import IntEnum, auto


class CustomIntEnum(IntEnum):
    def __int__(self) -> int:
        return int.__int__(int(self.value))


class Ex(CustomIntEnum):
    x = 0
    y = auto()


print(f"ex.x = {Ex.x} is of type {type(Ex.x)}")
print(f"ex.y = {Ex.y} is of type {type(Ex.y)}")


array = [5, 6, 7, 8]
print(f"but it can be used as index, for example in {array}[ex.x] => {array[Ex.x]}")
```

results in:

```
0 is of type <enum 'ex'>
1 is of type <enum 'ex'>
but it can be used as index, for example in [5, 6, 7, 8][ex.x] => 5

Process finished with exit code 0
```